# LINQ way to change my inefficient program

Tags: linq

Please consider the following records

[image]

I'm trying to flatten and group the data by `Robot Name` then by `date` + `Left Factory` time then group the address(es) for that date and time.  Notice that some of the `Left Factory` times are identical.

I wrote the code below and it works. It gives me the output that I want. I was a Perl developer so what you see below is from that mentality.  I'm sure there is a better way of doing it in LINQ.  A little help please.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (args.Length < 0){
        Console.WriteLine("Input file name is required");
        return;
    }


  List<string>  rawlst = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]).ToList<string>();

    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>> dicDriver = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>>();



    foreach (string ln in rawlst)
    {
        try
        {
            List<string> parts = new List<string>();
            parts = ln.Split(',').ToList<string>();

            string[] dtparts = parts[1].Split('/');
            string[] dttime = parts[15].Split(':');
            DateTime dtrow = new DateTime(
                int.Parse(dtparts[2]), int.Parse(dtparts[0]), int.Parse(dtparts[1]),
                int.Parse(dttime[0]), int.Parse(dttime[1]), int.Parse(dttime[2]));

            string rowAddress = parts[7] + " " + parts[9] + " " + parts[10] + " " + parts[11];

            if (!dicDriver.Keys.Contains(parts[3]))
            {
                Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> thisRec = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();
                thisRec.Add(dtrow, new List<string>() { rowAddress });

                dicDriver.Add(parts[3], thisRec);

            }
            else
            {
                Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>> thisDriver = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<string>>();

                thisDriver = dicDriver[parts[3]];
                if (!thisDriver.Keys.Contains(dtrow))
                {
                    dicDriver[parts[3]].Add(dtrow, new List<string>() { rowAddress });
                }
                else
                {
                    dicDriver[parts[3]][dtrow].Add(rowAddress);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR:" + ln);
        }
    }

 //output
    string filename = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".out";
    foreach (var name in dicDriver.Keys)
    {
        foreach (var dd in dicDriver[name])
        {

                Console.Write(name + "," + dd.Key + ",");
            File.AppendAllText(filename, name + "," + dd.Key + Environment.NewLine);
            foreach (var addr in dd.Value)
            {
                Console.Write("\t\t" + addr + Environment.NewLine);
                File.AppendAllText(filename, "\t" + addr + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }
        Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        File.AppendAllText(filename, Environment.NewLine);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();   
}
```

Comment: You are creating a `new List<string>` , storing it in `rawlst` and then immediately deleting it - why? `File.ReadAllLines` returns a `string[]` - why are you copying it into a list after reading? Can you show the actual input format and not the unrelated picture?

Comment: @NetMage not sure if I understand.  I'm newing up ` List<string> rawlst = new List<string>();` which is now an empty list of `string` and then on the second line I read all lines of the file and assign it to the rawlst.  While it's redundant, I'm not sure if it's wrong.  no?

Comment: @Zuzlx You need to get to the third floor, so run up to the third floor, then to the second and then back to the third. Nothing wrong with that, as long as it gets you where you want. Jokes aside, the empty list you generate is thrown away because you redirect the only reference to it (`rawlst`) to a completely new list which you get by reading the file.

Comment: Why do what you are doing instead of doing `var rawlst = File.ReadAllLines(args[0]);` ? What are you accomplishing?

Comment: Thanks guys.  Fixed.  Anything else pops out?

Comment: It always works best to untangle the jobs to be done. Like, first read the file content into a list of class instances, where the class has all required properties (`FactoryId, Date, etc.). Then you have an object collection to process with LINQ.

Comment: @GertArnold Thank you.  Great suggestion.  Would that be preferable than loading the data into a `datatable` and running linq queries on it?

Comment: Yes, because it's strong typed so you can benefit from intellisense. You could reduce your question to showing the class, some code that creates a collection of it and a first attempt at the grouping in LINQ. In fact, the file reading stuff is irrelevant to what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate your concerns: separate your input from the processing and from the output.

For example: suppose you would have to read your input from a database instead from a CSV file? Would that seriously change the way your process your fetched data? In your design, fetching the data is mixed with processing: although you know that the data that you want to process contains something like `FactoryProcesses`, you decide to present eache `FactoryProcess` as a string. A `FactoryProcess` is not a string. It describes how and when and who processed something in your factory. That is not a string, is it? However, it might be represented internally as a string, but the outside world should not know this. This way, if you change your `FactoryProcess` from being read by a CSV-file, to something provided by a database, the users of your `FactoryProcess` won't see any difference.

Separation of concerns makes your code easier to understand, easier to test, easier to change, and better to re-use.

So let's separate!

```
IEnumerable<FactoryProcess> ReadFactoryProcesses(string fileName)
{
     // TODO: check fileName not null, file exists
     using (var fileReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
     {
         // read the file Line by Line and split each line into one FactoryProcess object
         string line = fileReader.ReadLine();
         while (line != null)
         {
              // one line read, convert to FactoryProcess and yield return:
              FactoryProcess factoryProcess = this.ToFactoryProcess(line);
              yield return factoryProcess;

              // read next line:
              line = fileReader.ReadLine();
         }
    }               
}
```

I'll leave the conversion of a read line into a `FactoryProcess` up to you. Tip: if the items in your lines are separated by a comma, or something similar, consider using Nuget Package CSVHelper. It makes if easier to convert a file into a sequence of `FactoryProcesses`.

> I want to group the data by Robot Name then by date + Left Factory time then group the address(es) for that date and time.

First of all: make sure that the FactoryProcess class has the properties you actually need. Separate this representation from what it is in a file. Apparently you want to tread date + left factory as one item that represents the Date and Time that it left the factory. So Let's create a DateTime property for this.

```
class FactoryProcess
{
    public int Id {get; set}
    public int PartNo {get; set;}
    public string RobotName {get; set;}      // or if desired: use a unique RobotId
    ...

    // DateTimes: ArrivalTime, OutOfFactoryTime, LeftFactoryTime
    public DateTime ArrivalTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime OutOfFactoryTime {get; set;}
    public DateTime LeftFactoryTime {get; set;}
```

}

The reason that I put Date and Time into one DateTime, is because it will solve problems if an item arrives on 23:55 and leaves on 00:05 next day.

A procedure that converts a read CSV-line to a FactoryProcess should interpret your dates and times as strings and convert to FactoryProcess. You can create a constrcuctor for this, or a special Factory class

```
public FactoryProcess InterpretReadLine(string line)
{
    // TODO: separate the parts, such that you've got the strings dateTxt, arrivalTimeTxt, ...
     DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dateTxt);
     TimeSpan arrivalTime = TimeSpan.Parse(arrivalTimeTxt);
     TimeSpan outOfFactoryTime = TimeSpan.Parse(outOfFactoryTimeTxt);
     TimeSpan leftFactoryTime = TimeSpan.Parse(leftFactoryTimeTxt);

    return new FactoryProces
    {
        Id = ...
        PartNo = ..
        RobotName = ...

        // The DateTimes:
        ArrivalTime = date + arrivalTime,
        OutOfFactoryTime = date + outOfFactoryTime,
        LeftFactoryTime = date + leftFactoryTime,
    };
}
```

Now that you've created a proper method to convert your CSV-file into a sequence of `FactoryProcesses`, let's process them

> I want to group the data by Robot Name then by date + Left Factory time then group the address(es) for that date and time.

```
var result = fetchedFactoryProcesses.GroupBy(

    // parameter KeySelector: make groups of FactoryProcesses with same RobotName:
    factoryProcess => factoryProcess.RobotName,

    // parameter ResultSelector: from every group of FactoryProcesses with this RobotName
    // make one new Object:
    (robotName, processesWithThisRobotName) => new
    {
        RobotName = robotName,

        // Group all processes with this RobotName into groups with same LeftFactoryTime:
        LeftFactory = processesWithThisRobotName.GroupBy(

            // KeySelector: make groups with same LeftFactoryTime
            process => process.LeftFactoryTime,

            // ResultSelector: from each group of factory processes with the same LeftFactoryTime
            (leftFactoryTime, processesWithThisLeftFactoryTime) => new
            {
                LeftFactoryTime = leftFactoryTime,
                FactoryProcesses = processesWithThisLeftFactoryTime,

                // or even better: select only the properties you actually plan to use
                FactoryProcesses = processesWithThisLeftFactoryTime.Select(process => new
                {
                     Id = process.Id,
                     PartNo = process.PartNo,
                     ...

                     // not needed: you know the value, because it is in this group
                     // RobotName = process.RobotName,
                     // LeftFactoryTime = process.LeftFactoryTime,
                }),
            })
});
```

For completeness: grouping your code together:

```
void ProcessData(string fileName)
{
     var fetchedFactoryProcesses = ReadFactoryProcess(fileName);  // fetch the data
     var groups = fetchFactoryProcesses.ToGroups();               // put into groups
     this.Display(groups);                                        // output result;
}
```

Because I separated the input from the conversion of strings to FactoryProcesses, and separated this conversion from the grouping, it will be easy to test the classes separately:

- your CSV-reader should return any file that is divided into lines, even if it does not contain FactoryProcesses
- your conversion from read line to FactoryProcess should convert any string that is in the proper format, whether it is read from a file or gathered any other way
- your grouping should group any sequence of FactoryProcesses, whether they come from a CSV-file or from a database or `List<FactoryProcess>`, which is very convenient, because in your tests it is way easier to create a test list, than a test CSV-file.

If in future you decide to change the source of your sequence of FactoryProcesses, for instance it comes from a database instead of a CSV-file, your grouping won't change. Or if you decide to support entering and leaving factories on different dates (multiple date values) only the conversion changes. If you decide to display the results in a tree-like fashion, or decide to write the groups in a database, your reading, conversion, grouping, etc won't change: what a high degree or re-usability!

Separating your concerns made it much easier to understand how to solve your grouping problem, without the hassle of splitting your read lines and converting Date + LeftFactory into one value.

Comment: Thank you Harald. I'm reading and re-reading your answer again until I fully understand it.  I will also give it a try to make sure I get the expected behavior.